# What is causing a site to hang before first byte

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, debugging, laravel-4

I was developing on a local Laravel 4.1 site (specifically `andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site` package) when the site suddenly refused to load. It hangs without loading any data. The only thing I changed between then was updating bootstrap to 3.1.1. I thought perhaps this did it, so I reverted back to 3.0.0, but that didn't fix the problem.

I can access the local URL and see xdebug dump a profile for the site, which goes to completion, however, nothing shows in the browser. Headers aren't even transmitted according to HTTP Headers Chrome ext. Google SpeedTracer also shows no network activity.

However, if I introduce syntax errors anywhere in the code, I get a nice clean Exception error that loads right up in Whoops.

Is there a fitting tool I can use to track down exactly what file is causing the browser load to hang from the first byte?

Comment: That site is unfortunately notorious for slow-loading problems. Apparently it's often related to basset, which is unfortunately no longer maintained. See https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/issues/148

Comment: Removed Basset from service providers list and composer.json, ran update, but no dice. Still hung.

Comment: As it turns out, it was the unclosed line `@if (preg_match('~/(items|reports)~i', Request::path())` in a template causing the hang. Apparently when there is a missing closing `)`, Blade just hangs instead of completing the render.

Comment: Ahh.. ok well good to know. Grats on finding the issue :)